# MySQL Get rows with datetime type from last month

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, mysqli

I'm trying to display messages that have been sent in the past month. If today's date is `11/08/2014` then I want to show messages with date: `11/07/14 - 11/08/14`.

The date field on my database has this value `2014-08-10 17:20:28` (type: datetime)

I'm using the following query but it doesn't work, I think the problem is the time after the date? I removed the `%h:%i:%s` but it's still not working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE ...... 
AND (date_sent BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 %h:%i:%s') 
AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `date_sent` is already a `datetime`, there's no need at all for `date_format()` calls. MySQL can compare its own date formats easily:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE date_sent >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be the `CURRENT_DATE` value you're using, try using `NOW()`

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE ...
AND date_sent <= NOW()
AND date_sent >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
ORDER BY date_sent DESC;
```